# Using Ancestry gem through an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an Article that has many Comments. I would like to have users make comments to other user comments using Ancestry gem.

In the article show view, I am looping through `@article.comments` and setting the link to create a new comment, like so:

```
= link_to "Comment Reply", new_reply_path(:parent_id => reply).
```

When I click on a link it takes me to a new comment page, but when I click create a comment button, I get an error:

> Routing Error: No route matches for {:action=> “show”, :controller =>
>   “articles”}.

Anyone has had similar problems/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Your best resource for understanding how to accomplish is through the railscasts.com episode where Ryan Bates does basically the same thing your are asking about.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry

Good luck!